# convergence test of series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{4^n}{n^3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Help me to show whether this series converges or diverges.
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \dfrac{4^n}{n^3}$$

Comment: Exponentials win unless there is another exponential that kills the first one...

Answer (score 2):

If $a_n=\frac{4^n}{n^3}$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{4^{n+1}}{(n+1)^3}}{\frac{4^n}{n^3}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac4{(1+\frac1n)^3}>1$$

Comment: So this is a power series? since u take limit of the ratio

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/dAlembertRatioTest.html

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Apply L'Hospital's rule to the function $$f(x) = \frac{4^x}{x^3}$$ a few times and conclude that $$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$$

Answer (score 0):

You can use root test,$$a_n=\frac{4^n}{n^3}$$ $$\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}={4\over (n^{1\over n})^3}=4>1$$

So  The Series is divergent.